# Select rows where ColA=ColB and also add a new column that tells whether the original data in ColA is repeated

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, case, having

I am trying to figure out how to query a table (the table is actually a result set, so it will be a subquery), group it by `ColA=ColB` (see below), and create a calculated field all in one step.

So, if my test data looks like

```
ColA    ColB    ColC
```

```
1       1       aaa 
1       2       bbbb    
1       3       cccc    
2       2       dddd    
3       3       eeee    
3       4       ffff    
3       5       gggg    
3       6       hhhh    
4       4       iiii    
5       5       jjjj    
6       6       kkkk    
6       7       llll    
6       8       mmmm
```

---

I would like to retrieve only rows where `ColA=ColB` and also add a new column that tells me whether the original data in `ColA` was repeated.  See below.

```
ColA   ColB    ColC    multiples
```

```
1      1       aaaa    yes
2       2       dddd    no
3       3       eeee    yes
4       4       iiii    no
5       5       jjjj    no
6       6       kkkk    yes
```

Can someone help me out with the syntax?  I have been playing with Group By's and SubSelects to no avail.  Do I need to use a case statement to for the multiples field?

Answer (score 7):

It's more helpful to post create table and insert statements instead of Desc table and select * from table_name; http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2005/06/how-to-ask-questions.html

```
create table test_repeat(
   cola number,
   colb number,
   colc varchar2(20)
   );
     
insert into test_repeat values (1,1,'aaa'); 
insert into test_repeat values (1,2,'bbbb');    
insert into test_repeat values (1,3,'cccc');    
insert into test_repeat values (2,2,'dddd');    
insert into test_repeat values (3,3,'eeee'); 
insert into test_repeat values (3,4,'ffff');    
insert into test_repeat values (3,5,'gggg');    
insert into test_repeat values (3,6,'hhhh');    
insert into test_repeat values (4,4,'iiii');    
insert into test_repeat values (5,5,'jjjj');    
insert into test_repeat values (6,6,'kkkk');    
insert into test_repeat values (6,7,'llll');    
insert into test_repeat values (6,8,'mmmm');
commit;
```

1. You can use the Oracle analytic function [Lead](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions086.htm#SQLRF00656)  to look through your result set to see if colA is the same for the next row (after ordering it..) like..

   select * from
   (select colA, colb,
   (case when colA = (lead(cola) over
   (partition by colA order by cola, colb))
   then 'Yes'
   else 'No'
   end) multiples,
   colc
   from test_repeat)
   where colA = colb
   /

   ```
      COLA       COLB MUL COLC
   ```

   ---

   ```
         1          1 Yes aaa
         2          2 No  dddd
         3          3 Yes eeee
         4          4 No  iiii
         5          5 No  jjjj
         6          6 Yes kkkk
   ```
2. Or you can get the count for each value of COLA and compare it to see if there are duplicates...

   select a.colA, a.colb, a.colc,
   (case when (select count(*) from test_repeat t where t.cola = a.colA) > 1
   then 'Yes'
   else 'No'
   end) Repeat
   from test_repeat a
   where colA = colB
   /

   ```
      COLA       COLB COLC                 REP
   ```

   ---

   ```
         1          1 aaa                  Yes
         2          2 dddd                 No
         3          3 eeee                 Yes
         4          4 iiii                 No
         5          5 jjjj                 No
         6          6 kkkk                 Yes
   ```

They are both equally simple, but **I would suggest the analytic function approach as I have found it to be generally faster for all Queries** I have worked with in the past.

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL> select *
  2    from test_repeat
  3   order by cola
  4  /

      COLA       COLB COLC
---------- ---------- --------------------
         1          2 bbbb
         1          1 aaa
         1          3 cccc
         2          2 dddd
         3          4 ffff
         3          3 eeee
         3          5 gggg
         3          6 hhhh
         4          4 iiii
         5          5 jjjj
         6          6 kkkk
         6          7 llll
         6          8 mmmm
         7          9 nnnn

14 rows selected.

SQL> select cola "ColA"
  2       , max(decode(colb,cola,colb)) "ColB"
  3       , max(decode(colb,cola,colc)) "ColC"
  4       , case count(*) when 1 then 'no' else 'yes' end "multiples"
  5    from test_repeat
  6   group by cola
  7  having cola = max(decode(colb,cola,colb))
  8   order by cola
  9  /

      ColA       ColB ColC                 mul
---------- ---------- -------------------- ---
         1          1 aaa                  yes
         2          2 dddd                 no
         3          3 eeee                 yes
         4          4 iiii                 no
         5          5 jjjj                 no
         6          6 kkkk                 yes

6 rows selected.
```

Performancewise, this SQL is approximately equal to Rajesh' first query. So you can choose the one you are more comfortable with.

```
SQL> set autotrace on
SQL> select * from
  2  (select colA, colb,
  3         (case when colA = (lead(cola) over
  4                            (partition by colA order by cola, colb))
  5              then 'Yes'
  6              else 'No'
  7         end) multiples,
  8         colc
  9    from test_repeat)
 10    where colA = colb
 11  /

      COLA       COLB MUL COLC
---------- ---------- --- --------------------
         1          1 Yes aaa
         2          2 No  dddd
         3          3 Yes eeee
         4          4 No  iiii
         5          5 No  jjjj
         6          6 Yes kkkk

6 rows selected.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1491815685

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |             |    14 |   574 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW               |             |    14 |   574 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   WINDOW SORT       |             |    14 |   532 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEST_REPEAT |    14 |   532 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("COLA"="COLB")

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          4  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
         15  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
        421  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        238  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          1  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          6  rows processed

SQL> /

      COLA       COLB MUL COLC
---------- ---------- --- --------------------
         1          1 Yes aaa
         2          2 No  dddd
         3          3 Yes eeee
         4          4 No  iiii
         5          5 No  jjjj
         6          6 Yes kkkk

6 rows selected.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1491815685

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |             |    14 |   574 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW               |             |    14 |   574 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   WINDOW SORT       |             |    14 |   532 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEST_REPEAT |    14 |   532 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("COLA"="COLB")

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          7  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
        421  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        238  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          1  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          6  rows processed

SQL> select cola "ColA"
  2       , max(decode(colb,cola,colb)) "ColB"
  3       , max(decode(colb,cola,colc)) "ColC"
  4       , case count(*) when 1 then 'no' else 'yes' end "multiples"
  5    from test_repeat
  6   group by cola
  7  having cola = max(decode(colb,cola,colb))
  8   order by cola
  9  /

      ColA       ColB ColC                 mul
---------- ---------- -------------------- ---
         1          1 aaa                  yes
         2          2 dddd                 no
         3          3 eeee                 yes
         4          4 iiii                 no
         5          5 jjjj                 no
         6          6 kkkk                 yes

6 rows selected.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3021378319

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |             |    14 |   532 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER             |             |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   SORT GROUP BY     |             |    14 |   532 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEST_REPEAT |    14 |   532 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("COLA"=MAX(DECODE("COLB","COLA","COLB")))

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          7  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
        421  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        238  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          1  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          6  rows processed

SQL> /

      ColA       ColB ColC                 mul
---------- ---------- -------------------- ---
         1          1 aaa                  yes
         2          2 dddd                 no
         3          3 eeee                 yes
         4          4 iiii                 no
         5          5 jjjj                 no
         6          6 kkkk                 yes

6 rows selected.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3021378319

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |             |    14 |   532 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER             |             |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   SORT GROUP BY     |             |    14 |   532 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEST_REPEAT |    14 |   532 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("COLA"=MAX(DECODE("COLB","COLA","COLB")))

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          7  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
        420  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        238  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          1  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          6  rows processed

SQL> set autotrace off
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a subselect for the `multiples` column. No grouping is needed. Write something like:

```
select ColA, ColB, ColC, 
       (CASE
        WHEN (select b.ColA from thistable b where b.ColA = a.ColA) > 1 THEN 'yes'
        ELSE 'no'
        END)
from thistable a
where ColA = ColB
```

Comment: -1 This is untested SQL. The END keyword is missing and if you add that, the statement will still fail with "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Answer (score 0):

I was not aware of the lead function, very nice.  Rob and Rajesh, thanks for the answers so far, I think I was able to partly answer my own question using two subqueries and an outer join.

I am guessing my query is not as efficient as the others posted, but I wonder if folks could comment on this query.  Will it always work? Can it be tweaked to make it more efficient? *It still needs to put in 'yes' or 'no' for multiples, right now it puts the multiple count or a null for 0.*

> ```
> SELECT BB.ColA, ColB, ColC, AA.CNT 
> FROM
> (SELECT ColA, count(*) as CNT FROM TMPY where ColA<>ColB Group by ColA)  AA, 
> (SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC FROM TMPY WHERE COLA=COLB ) BB 
> WHERE
> AA.COLa(+)=BB.COLB order by bb.ColA;
> ```